# I am getting an error with the foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

This is my code:

```
$messages = get_msg();
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'].'Sent</strong></br>';
    echo $message['message'].'<br/></br>';
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xamp\htdocs\chatbox\index.php

Why is my argument invalid for the `foreach`?

Comment: What is get_msg?

Comment: Does your get_msg return an array of items or just a item? or nothing?

Comment: looks like get_msg() returns only one message

Answer (score 0):

Php said got something wrong in $messages argument. Maybe you should checking your get_msg() function, make sure function result's type is array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of the result you are getting from `get_msg()` function. To loop through a `foreach` loop you have to pass a array to the `foreach` loop. check the return type of `get_msg()` by just print values that return by `get_msg()`

```
 print_r(get_msg());
```

refer this for more information about `foreach` loop [link](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)